# docker: Viewing network CIDR

Tags: docker, docker-network

When I perform `hostname -I` on my workstation, I am able to see all my IPs, including both the one belonging to my actual physical interface (say `eth0`) as also the virtual ones (in my case the ones created by the `docker` service).

e.g.

```
hostname -I
10.11.22.191 172.17.0.1 172.18.0.1 172.19.0.1
```

Is there a way (other than `docker network inspect <docker_network_name>`) to be able to quickly view the network address of the docker networks?

```
$ docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                   DRIVER              SCOPE
9eef357133bc        bridge                 bridge              local
b9b95911a396        docker_gwbridge        bridge              local
d8c31ff5a231        host                   host                local
a647972b5420        myapp-docker_default   bridge              local
233a5ff15985        myapp-docker_pub_net   bridge              local
256b6b7e1917        none                   null                local
```